# Am I logically reiterating the same code block in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra

What is the difference between these two lines of Ruby code?

```ruby
if params.values.any? { |value| value == "" }
```

and

```ruby
@post = current_user.posts.build(title: params[:post][:title], content: params[:post][:content])
```

The contexts in which they are used are as follows, respectively:

```ruby
post '/builds' do
  redirect_if_not_logged_in
  if params.values.any? {|value| value == ""}
    erb :'builds/new', #locals: {message: "Unable to Continue!"}
  else
    user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    @build = Build.create(title: params[:title], budget: params[:budget], user_id: params[:user.id])
    redirect to "/builds/#{@build.id}"
  end
end
```

and

```ruby
post "/builds" do
  redirect_if_not_logged_in
  @build = current_user.builds.build(title: params[:post][:title], content: params[:build][:content])
  if @build.save
    redirect "/builds"
  else
    erb :"/builds/new.html"
  end
end
```

Comment: You mean apart from those two lines having basically nothing in common? I'm not sure what you're asking about here.  Why do you have two handlers for the same path?

Comment: im practicing on writing the same code differently,

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Those two lines are so completely different I can't even begin to find ways they're similar.

Comment: ok thank im wrong than. You answered it successfully

Comment: Hope that helped? This Ruby code looks fine, but I'm not sure what the commonality is between the blocks other than they both purport to answer `/builds`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if params.values.any? {|value| value == ""}
     erb :'builds/new', #locals: {message: "Unable to Continue!"}
```

What you're doing here is returning an error message if any of the parameter values are empty. This can happen if the user didn't fill out one of the form fields on the page.

```
 @post = current_user.posts.build(title: params[:post][:title], content: params[:post][:content])
```

This creates a new post object using the given parameters. If you didn't have that first code block, this might possibly set one of the values to an empty string (`""`).

There are other ways to do this (specifically, model-level validations), but hopefully that helps you figure out what's going on here.